# How to use values in parameter of invocation of the function?

Tags: javascript

I am not sure if the question has the right terms/words but I have the code and should explain the problem.

```js
function canDrive(age,_yes,_no){
 if (age >= 16) {
  
  return _yes;
} else {

  return _no;
}
}

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = canDrive(30,"YES WAY","NOWAY");
}
myFunction();
```

```html
<p>Can he drive <span id="demo"></span></p>
```

The problem is that invocation where i do not have access is structured like this. It seems to be valid

```
canDrive(30)("YES WAY","NOWAY");
```

How can i access YES WAY and NOWAY ? in the above scenario? If I can understand how it works i can solve a big problem. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by, access YES WAY and NOWAY?

Comment: I guess there is a mistake with the formatting of your code or maybe the way you understand how the function works. You need to pass parameters to the function and store the returned value to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your question, I assume you are looking for this:

```js
function canDrive(age) {
  return function(yes, no) {
    return age >= 16 ? yes : no;
  }
}

console.log(canDrive(30)("YES WAY", "NOWAY"));
```

`canDrive` returns a closure which returns one of the two supplied arguments based on `age`.

Comment: so is `("YES WAY",NOWAY")` called and argument or a closure?

Comment: `canDrive` is a function. `canDrive(30)` is a function call with argument `30` and returns an unnamed `Function`. This returned function 'closes' over the `age` argument of `canDrive`. Thus it is called a 'closure'. You then call the closure with two arguments `"YES WAY"` and `"NOWAY"`. This is equivalent to: `var closure = canDrive(30); console.log(closure("YES WAY", "NOWAY"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
var canDrive = function(age) {
   return function(_yes, _no) {
       if  (age >= 16)
           return _yes;
       return _no;
   }
}
```